# Lock database by password in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I use SQL Server 2012 and C# to create a project. I have a database in SQL Server to build the project. I want hide the database from all users just Admin can obtain the database.

Please help me to find the way to set a password on database or any other way?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine

Comment: SQL Server is ***NOT*** a file-based database which you can "protect" with a password. That just won't work. You need to setup **logins** and **permissions** to control who can see and do what.